# Constructor with parameters for XAML elements in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create XAML element with parametrized constructor using dependency injection service? Or is there some other way to pass dependencies? I would like to have Behavior with some dependency services. I thought the **DependencyResolver.ResolveUsing** is going to solve my problem, but this method only allows to resolve special types of objects like renderers or effects. I can bind to viewmodel properties but this will produce large xaml instead of just simple `<SomeBehavior/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer satisfied my needs so I share my solution. I use StaticResources (Application.Current.Resources) as ServiceLocator. This way I can access required services from my behavior without boilerplate code. Yes, I know it is not a perfect solution, but seems the best in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that setting dependency for XAML element is not supported.

You can check the Microsoft document about [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating). Please feel free to contact us If you have other question